# Mvvmcross support NotifyPropertyChanged event where event args contain the old value?

Tags: c#, mvvmcross

There is a UIHealthBar which is binded to a viewmodel property that is changed from 5 to 10. I would like to animate it with filled color from a old value (5) to new value (10). How can I do it in mvvmcross with a better approach ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be done with a pair of viewmodel properties - perhaps a tuple that is always changed together - e.g.

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        // subscribe for health updates here
    }

    public class HealthTuple
    {
        public double Old {get;set;}
        public double New {get;set;}
    }

    private HealthTuple _health; 
    public HealthTuple Health 
    {
       get { return _health; }
       set { _health = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Health); }
    } 

    private void OnNewHealth(HealthMessage message)
    {
        Health = new HealthTuple() { Old = _health.New, New = message.Value };
    }
}
```

Your custom UIView - the `UIHealthBar` can then expose either a single property or two properties and you can bind these to the ViewModel's Health values. Drawing/animating the display is then 'normal UI kit work'

Comment: I see mvvmlight code that implement this directly on "void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(string propertyName, T oldValue, T newValue, bool broadcast)"

Comment: you can use inpc to send a custom propertychangedmessage if you want to - but none of the standard windows controls know what to do with that extended message, nor do any of the standard android or ios controls that i've extended for mvx. If you think it's important to support this, then by all means implement it yourself - it's just a custom eventargs class. you are also welcome to open a feature request on github - but I don't personally expect many use cases to use this, so I don't personally expect this to be high priority

Comment: actually looking at https://github.com/ericschultz/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(NET35)/ObservableObject.cs I don't think mvvmlight actually sends the oldValue and newValue to the UI either

Comment: I am look at [https://github.com/ericschultz/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(NET35)/ViewModelBase.cs](https://github.com/ericschultz/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(NET35)/ViewModelBase.cs), I think it can be used instead of touching the mvvmcross base.